# How can I see the text output of a non-Geometry node?

Tags: geometry-nodes, output

is it possible to see the result of this multiplication as a text ? like a class console output if you're coding.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, simply use the `Viewer` node (can be found in the menu under *"Output "*).

The output is then visible in the *Spreadsheet*.

However, the evaluation of a node is always context specific. Therefore you would have to plug an additional geometry into the viewer node.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! this should do for now.